# Is it possible to access contact information screen in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, contacts

i am currently working in iPhone application, using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to create contact screen in my application, then i select email field and it comes to previous screen, but i want to the app should not allow the user to pick the email id, how to make this action? Below i have mentioned screenshot for your reference, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by  "i want to access only phone number field"

Comment: the app should not allow the user to pick the email id

Comment: R u there? thank for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement following delegate method and check condition with Property as follows.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

    if(property == kABPersonPhoneProperty)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //This should be here only if phone property is there.
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify your view controller to be the delegate of the appropriate [AddressBookUI.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) type (e.g. `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate` or `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate`) and then write a method to respond to the appropriate protocol event (e.g. `shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson` or `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`). Check out the protocol references at the [Address Book UI Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007082).